# Junk printing after linked list head deletion

Tags: c, linked-list

Each class room student(`aluno`) represents a linked list node.

After deleting by student name, my print function prints junk on the removed students former "position".

[EDIT] Added full code.

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    char *name;
    int number;
    struct student *next;
};

struct student *constructor(char *name, int number){
    struct student *newNode = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    newNode->name = name;
    newNode->number = number;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

struct student *newStudent(struct student *node, char *name, int number){
    if (node == NULL)
        constructor(name, number);

    struct student *p = node;

    while(p->next != NULL) p = p->next;
    p->next = constructor(name,number);

    return node;
}

struct student *removeAluno(struct student *node, char *name){
    struct student *p = node;

    if (strcmp(p->name,name) == 0){
        struct student *devolver = p->next;
        free(p);
        return devolver;
    } //Removes head

    while(p->next != NULL){

        if (strcmp(p->next->name,name) == 0){

            if (p->next->next == NULL){ //Removes last element
                struct student *remover = p->next;
                p->next = NULL;
                free(remover);
            } 
            else{ //Removes any element between head and last
                struct student *remover = p->next; 
                p->next = p->next->next;
                free(remover);
            }

        }   
        else 
            p = p->next;
    }

    return p;
}

void printClass(struct student *students){
    struct student *p = students;

    while(p->next != NULL){
        printf("\nNome: %s, Numero: %d",p->name,p->number);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\nNome: %s, Numero: %d",p->name,p->number);
    printf("\n");
}


int main(){
    struct student *a = constructor("Michael",15);
    newStudent(a,"John",14);
    newStudent(a,"Jack",13);
    printClass(a);
    removeAluno(a,"Michael");
    printClass(a);
    removeAluno(a,"John");
    printClass(a);
    removeAluno(a,"Jack");
    printClass(a);
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
//list after inserting Michael, John, Jack (in this order)
Nome: Michael, Numero: 15
Nome: John, Numero: 14
Nome: Jack, Numero: 13
//list after removing Michael
o, Numero: 7283408 //junk
Nome: John, Numero: 14
Nome: Jack, Numero: 13
//list after removing John
o, Numero: 7283408 //junk
Nome: Jack, Numero: 13
//list after removing Jack
Nome: ╚6o, Numero: 7283408 //junk
```

Comment: Mixing Portuguese with English in code? Please refactor your question to use only English variable, functions and type names.

Comment: In print function you should remove second last `printf` as it try to dereference pointer to `NULL` which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ameyCU I think it is not `NULL` at that point...

Comment: Can you show your complete code?

Comment: Anyway, I think there are some other problems in this code. For instance I don't see any deallocation of the strings... Which makes me wonder, how they are allocated.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe it is not `NULL` but the check should be for both . It should check `p` also .

Comment: @Jezor refactored.

Comment: @ameyCU second printf does not point to NULL. Points to a node which next element is NULL. In that conditions, I can print node's name and number.

Comment: @MartínMuñozdelRío full code added

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe... But does that condemns list printing ?

Comment: What if you remove the `head` element? Then your code is loosing it.

Comment: I believe that is the problem. Head identification and treatment. Any suggestion?

Comment: just have a dummy node as the head, which will never be deleted. Or a pointer to the first element which can be updated in the removal function.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `return` struct pointers but in `main` you do not use their return. What you need to do is this in `main`-

```
a=newStudent(a,"John",14);
```

same for other functions .

Comment: It will loose the head. I think the OP should take a look at the canonical linked lists implementations.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why would it loose head ?

Comment: Actually no, it won't, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer to pointers:

For example, yo can change your remove function to:

```
struct student *removeAluno(struct student **node, char *name){
    struct student *p = *node;

    if (strcmp(p->name,name) == 0){
        struct student *devolver = p->next;
        free(p);

        *node = devolver;

        return devolver;
    } //Removes head

    while(p->next != NULL){

        if (strcmp(p->next->name,name) == 0){

            if (p->next->next == NULL){ //Removes last element
                struct student *remover = p->next;
                p->next = NULL;
                free(remover);

                *node = NULL;
            } 
            else{ //Removes any element between head and last
                struct student *remover = p->next; 
                p->next = p->next->next;
                free(remover);
            }

        }   
        else{ 
            p = p->next;

        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

And your print function, to avoid problems when the list is empty, can change to:

```
void printClass(struct student *students){
    if(students==NULL)
        return;

    struct student *p = students;

    while(p->next != NULL){
        printf("\nNome: %s, Numero: %d",p->name,p->number);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\nNome: %s, Numero: %d",p->name,p->number);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I have tried it, and get this output:

```
Nome: Michael, Numero: 15
Nome: John, Numero: 14
Nome: Jack, Numero: 13

Nome: John, Numero: 14
Nome: Jack, Numero: 13

Nome: Jack, Numero: 13
```